# Finding longest run of consecutive repeats of substrings in a string(python)

Tags: python, dna-sequence

This is from cs50, pset6 DNA, but I'm asking about a portion of the code. This code works perfectly for some substrings but is off for others and I have no idea what's wrong with my code, please help me figure out what's wrong with it. It works for small samples, but when I ran it in the huge file, it was off for two values. Feel free to blast me, it's my first time using StackOverflow. Thanks in advance:)

```
def count_max_repeat(sequence, dna_sample): 
    maxDna = 0
    temp = 0
    nextseq = 0
    index = 0
    #count how many times sequence occurs
    ranger = dna_sample.count(sequence, 0, len(dna_sample))

    #loop through dna_sample for how many times sequence occurs
    for count in range(ranger + 1):

        #find first occurence of index in string
        if (dna_sample.find(sequence, nextseq) != -1):
            if(count == 0):
                nextseq = dna_sample.find(sequence, nextseq)

            #if the next sequence isn't matching, reset counter of repeated substring
            if (dna_sample.find(sequence, nextseq) != nextseq):
                nextseq = dna_sample.find(sequence,nextseq)
                temp = 0
            else:    
                #record last position of sequence
                nextseq = dna_sample.find(sequence, nextseq) + len(sequence)
                temp += 1


            #checks if previous amount of repeated sequence is bigger, if not assigns maxDna to largest amount of repeating sequence
            if (temp > maxDna):      
                maxDna = temp
     print("maxDna: " + str(maxDna))
```

the parameter sequence is the substring, and the parameter dna_sample is the whole string

[dna_sample](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11SoHF6utKR_W2yoGiQiB2c3zAwLqmkDEfkYq3OVMQtM/edit)

[sequences](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f86qeyvSG2lvAhQAt5dajiAGcRGTj4emMO5EMuozGZo/edit?usp=sharing)

These are the files that are giving incorrect output. When running this program, the output(maxDna) should be 22,33,43,12,26,18,47,41 (Lavender's row).
What I'm getting is 17, 33, 43, 7, 26, 18, 47, 41.

Comment: Without informing readers of the smallest input that produced the incorrect output and compared it with the expected output, it would be rather difficult for most people even to attempt to answer.

Comment: ok, should i link the files then? I didn't link them because they were quite large. The large files are the smallest output which is incorrect.

Comment: how do I mark my question as complete? I solved it:)

Comment: You can add your own answer to your own question in the answer box below.